# Ошибка с2027 и c2227

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
class banyka
{
public:
    void print(struct Matrix *m);
    void input(struct Matrix *m);
    void trans(struct Matrix *m);
};

void banyka::print(struct Matrix* m)
{
    cout << "Созданая матрица" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m -> p; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m -> p; j++)
        {
            cout << m->matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void banyka::input(struct Matrix *m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m -> p; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m -> p; j++)
        {
            m -> matrix[i][j] = 10 + rand() % 50;
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу понять ошибку!

> Ошибка    C2027   использование неопределенного типа
> "Matrix"  Lab_num_one e:\ооп\lab_num_one\lab_num_one\mtp.h    11
>
> Ошибка    C2227   выражение слева от "->matrix" должно указывать на тип
> класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный
> тип   Lab_num_one e:\ооп\lab_num_one\lab_num_one\сm.h 22

Comment: А где ваш `Matrix`? Откуда компилятору о нем знать?

Comment: Он вынесен в заголовочный файл  в виде структуре и подключен

Comment: struct Matrix
    {
 const int p = 5;
 int matrix[5][5];
    };

Comment: Может закомментировали случайно include?

Comment: Нет, проверял код, ничего лишнего

Comment: Тут прежде всего должна быть ошибка компиляции структуры.
в пределах класса могут быть инициализированы только статические константные данные-члены целого типа

Comment: Можно по подробнее?

Comment: Тут изначально спроектировано неверно. Есть структура(которая в C++ тоже класс), в которой только массив, и класс с функциями. А смысл классов в том, что там и данные, и функции. Сделайте один класс, тогда матрица будет внутри, ее даже не надо будет передавать как параметр. Назовите как-то осмысленно. Что такое banyka?

Comment: Студент, так веселюсь. Сейчас переписал программу, всё работает, без ошибки(только не разбивал по файлам).

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что без точного примера кода дать доказательный ответ невозможно.

Comment: Выложить весь код? Что бы всё было ясно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ талантами телепата и провидца не обладает, и с неизвестными (необъявленными и неопределенными) типами (каковым в вашем примере является `Matrix`) не работает...

Comment: Программа грубо говоря работала, запустил сегодня и тут такая ошибка.

Comment: Слушайте, давайте еще обвиним "бага в компилере". Чудес не бывает, ошибка C2027 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c2dk0ah.aspx - не видит ваш компилятор определения `Matrix`, хоть вы тут все минусами залепите. Если вы не хотите сами себе помочь и дать нормальный текст, а не просто кричать "у меня все правильно!" (если правильно - то что вы от нас хотите? :)) - то кто ж вам доктор? Вопрос надо закрывать...

Comment: Я виню себя, что я такой ужасный.